# How to fix error duplicate entry: com/coremedia/iso/AbstractBoxParser$1.class?

Tags: android, video, video-compression, android-mediacodec

After add isoparser-1.0.6.jar into lib folder, I got error something like this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/coremedia/iso/AbstractBoxParser$1.class

And this is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/vdopialwsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.4-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-websockets-master.jar')
    compile files('libs/zcsprinterV.jar')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.2'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-resolver-minidns', version: '4.1.7'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-extensions', version: '4.1.7'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-tcp', version: '4.1.7'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-legacy', version: '4.1.7'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-sasl-provided', version: '4.1.7'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-android', version: '4.1.7'
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-bosh:4.1.7"
    compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:1.2.1'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1-tweaked-2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Endless-RecyclerView:1.0.3'
    compile 'life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5'
```

}

So, how to fix it?
Best Regards..

Comment: Now I know what's the problem. The problem is because there is 2 libraries isoparser-1.0.6.jar and life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0. When I removed that one, the project is running well

Comment: But how do you solve the problem if you still need to use both libraries?

Comment: have u solved this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long head-pain I finally solved the problem. as you mentioned the reason is isoparser. so please add this to your **build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
compile('life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.1.3-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude  group: 'com.googlecode.mp4parser', module: 'isoparser'
    }
```

Problem solved! Happy coding :)

Comment: After adding this in build.gradle app is getting crashed after tapping save button. Log says "Failed resolution of: Lcom/googlecode/mp4parser/FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl;"

Comment: There is an explanation in that [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336655/using-different-versions-of-same-library-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os?rq=1) in comments. Can you try ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to solve the issue. A possible solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367038/7398620) in case someone needs it.

Comment: Don't forget the paranthetis.