# Cannot build Signed APK because of external library(Third party library: life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0 )

Tags: android

I am using a third party library to trim a video but due to the use of proguard i am not able to build signed apk.... but after i exclude some classes in the app gradle file then i am able build the signed apk but cannot use the library.
I am stuck in this loop.

I am using this life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0 third party library to trim a video..
however when i try to build sign APK i get this error

Duplicate zip entry [com/coremedia/iso/a$1.class == isoparser-1.1.20.jar:com/coremedia/iso/AbstractBoxParser$1.class]

so to tackle above error i am doing this

```
compile ('life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0') {
        exclude  group: 'com.googlecode.mp4parser', module: 'isoparser'
    }
```

Now i am able to buid a signed APK but i am not able to use the above mentioned library as it gives this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/googlecode/mp4parser/FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl;
        at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.utils.TrimVideoUtils.genVideoUsingMp4Parser(TrimVideoUtils.java:72)
        at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.utils.TrimVideoUtils.startTrim(TrimVideoUtils.java:65)
        at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.K4LVideoTrimmer$5.execute(K4LVideoTrimmer.java:354)enter code here
        at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.utils.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:212)
        at
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by doing just what the above answer says https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367038/8900747 (combining both libraries) but in my case, i'm using [SiliCompressor](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor) and 
[AndroidDeveloperLB/VideoTrimmer](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/VideoTrimmer), and i also created a library just for anyone who comes across this issue and wants a quick fix :) https://github.com/tobioyelekan/VideoTrimmerCompressor